# Using iFrame with mvc3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, controller

I have Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetMenuContentFileToDisplay(int menuItemId)
{
    //......
    return File(fileAttributes.FilePath, fileAttributes.InternetMediaType,
                        Uri.EscapeUriString(fileAttributes.FileName));
}
```

I want to use this approach (which allows you to receive files) to display content in iframe. Is it possible to implement this for show HTM file?

This piece is necessary because of concealment from the user of the file structure and the need to check the file permissions.

I would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you want to display in this iframe? Why is your controller action returning a file and how is this related to the iframe? How do you intend to call this action from the client?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("DF", "GetMenuContentFileToDisplay",                                 new { menuItemId = 5 }) - it is download file. I want to display htm file into the <iframe>, and get the file from the controller using the index.

Comment: I need to display the file and do not show him the way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the file inline you could use an iframe:

```
<iframe src="@Url.Action("GetMenuContentFileToDisplay", new { menuItemId = "5" })"></iframe>
```

To avoid the file being downloaded you should not provide it a filename, only a `Content-Type`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetMenuContentFileToDisplay(int menuItemId)
{
    return File(
        fileAttributes.FilePath, 
        fileAttributes.InternetMediaType
    );
}
```

Obviously this will only work if the file content type is recognized by the browser (For example it's a `text/html` or `text/plain`). Otherwise the browser will once again prompt the user to download the file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the postscript to the code - forgot to add the Internet MediaType for htm. But the images will not check on html page.

Comment: What do you mean by *images won't check on html page*? How are they referenced?

Comment: How to set links to images that they are loaded?